# Retrieve an object field from a list of items with one map-filter lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

We have a List of SomeType items from which we would like to retrieve a particular item, perform a check on that item (filter), and if the criteria is fulfilled, then retrieve a particular String type field from the item (map), all in one expression

The concerned method interfaces are as follows. All is going fine until the last step, where we would like to map the filter result `Optional<SomeType>` into `Optional<String>`. Unfortunately we are not able to nail the syntax expected by the map call

```
public Optional<String> transform(final List<SomeType> aList)        
    return getAnItemFromTheList(aList)
            .filter(someFilterClass::anItemFulfillsCriteria)
            .map(???use getAStringTypeFieldFromTheItem() here???);

private Optional<SomeType> getAnItemFromTheList(final List<SomeType> aList) {...
public boolean anItemFulfillsCriteria(final SomeType anItem) {... //in a separate class of filter methods
private Optional<String> getAStringTypeFieldFromTheItem(final SomeType anItem) {...
```

Comment: you can do `.map(a -> getAStringTypeFieldFromTheItem(a)).orElse(Optional.empty())` but that can be simplified to `flatMap(a -> getAStringTypeFieldFromTheItem(a))` as [answered by Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52182532/1746118)...ofcourse method references for the lambda as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if I understood it correctly that `getAStringTypeFieldFromTheItem` will return an `Optional<String>`, thus you will end up with `Optional<Optional<String>>` after the `map`; thus just use `flatMap` instead of `map` to get that `Optional<String>` as a result

Comment: It looks like this: `return getAnItemFromTheList(aList)
            .filter(SomeFilterClass::anItemFulfillsCriteria)
            .flatMap(item -> getAStringTypeFieldFromTheItem(item));`

Comment: @LuCio it would be much nicer if the OP would use a method reference in the last `flatMap` though

Comment: I would prefer it too. But since OP didn't provide the class (at least its name) where the method `getAStringTypeFieldFromTheItem` is located, I've used the lamba expression.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what we needed. `getAStringTypeFieldFromTheItem` is in the same class (I tried to hint with private/public modifiers + comment in the question that only the filter method is in a different class, sorry if it was not clear) so we can use `this::getAStringTypeFieldFromTheItem` method reference